# Angular Owl Carousel

Tags: angular, carousel, ngfor, owl-carousel

I want to display data in carousel slider through ngFor. But it seems not to work.
This code works fine

```
<owl-carousel carouselClasses="inner-carousel owl-simple rows cols-1" [options]="introSlider">
<div class="intro-slide" style="background-image: url({{storeBannerUrls[0]}}); background-size: 100% 100%;"></div>
<div class="intro-slide" style="background-image: url({{storeBannerUrls[1]}}); background-size: 100% 100%;"></div>
</owl-carousel>
```

But I want to set url through a loop. Like

```
*ngFor="let url of storeBannerUrls"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to wrap you whole `divs` section into a `ng-template`, and then you need to include an `carouselSlide` like this.

```
<owl-carousel carouselClasses="inner-carousel owl-simple rows cols-1" [options]="introSlider">
  <ng-template carouselSlide>
     <div class="intro-slide" style="background-image: url({{storeBannerUrls[0]}}); background-size: 100% 100%;"></div>
     <div class="intro-slide" style="background-image: url({{storeBannerUrls[1]}}); background-size: 100% 100%;"></div>
  </ng-template>
</owl-carousel>
```